# undefined reference error for static class member when it is defined in .cpp file

Tags: c++, static, undefined-reference

This question may seem similar to other "undefined reference error when accessing static class member" questions. I have explored them and what I understood is I need to define the static class member separately in a source file, so that an object is created for the static class member that holds data.

My problem is that I am following definition rules but still get the undefined reference errors.

problem can be reproduced using this code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "src/a.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << a::x;
    return 0;
}
```

**src/a.hpp**

```
class a {
public:
    static int x;
};
```

**src/a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"

int a::x = 20;
```

I compile `main.cpp` using `g++ main.cpp -o main`. I have a `test` directory that has `main.cpp` and a sub directory `src`, `src` contains `a.hpp` and `a.cpp`.

The error resolves if i define the static variable within the header file, but other posts suggest it should lead to linker errors.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you actually compile, or link with, `a.cpp`. Defining the variable in a header file works because you only include that header in a single source file. In essence, you move `int a::x = 20;` to `main.cpp`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is my first c++ project and I am using a text editor(vscode), I suppose I am compiling it incorrectly. What is the correct way to compile this can you please specify

Comment: `g++ main.cpp src/a.cpp -o main` should do it, I think.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks. Is there a concise way to do this, since there can be several source file in a project in different directories?

Comment: At this point, you may wish to consider using a build automation system, such as [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) or [cmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)

Comment: I will explore them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the compile command I used, `g++ main.cpp -o main` does not compile src/a.cpp. Compile it with `g++ main.cpp src/a.cpp -o main` and it works fine.